# XCode: Button with changing uses and lots of cases to run through

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, storyboard

I'm very new to iOS Development/Xcode and have two questions.

If I wanted to have a button open a page based on something a user entered on a previous page e.g. if the user entered "Farm" the button will open a pre-made storyboard with a picture of a farm or if they entered "Cat" the button will open a storyboard with a picture of a cat and so on... How could I pull this off?

(I know this next one is common, so a link to a previous post is perfectly fine!)
My second question is how could I optimize the runtime of my app if I have a lot of cases like such to check through? I don't know enough syntax in Xcode to even pull off if-statements at this point in time as I downloaded the IDE last night, but I can understand the general approach based on any responses!

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is an Example

1. Create a ViewController Name it "FirstVC"
2. Create another ViewController Name it "SecondVC"
3. Creat another ViewController Name it "PictureVC"
4. Have three image named as "Farm,Dog,Cat" in your assets.

> FirstVc.Swift

```
class FirstVc.Swift : UIViewController{
           @IBOutlet weak var yourTextField.text : UITextField!

              //You can have textField here or a PickrView Where user select or enter something
                
             //create instance of secondVC which have a string variable named userInput and assign it the value given by the user
            
             // enter name any from "cat","farm","dog"
        
             if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC{
                            vc.userInput = yourTextField.text
        
                            // now push that view controller
        
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
             }            
       }
```

> SecondVC.Swift

```
class SecondVC : UIViewController{
               var userInput = ""        
    // this is your ibAction where you will pass the string to pictureVc you got from first vc
    
      @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender : Any){
    
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PictureVC") as? PictureVC{
                                vc.imageName = userInput
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                                
              }   
          }
      }
```

> PictureVc.Swift

```
class PictureVc : UIViewController{
            
               var imageName = "" 
               // your imageView     
               @IBOutlet weak var imageView!       
               // set image based on the imageName     
               imageView.image = UIImage(named : imageName)
                             
      }
```